# How to trigger a change in CSS from a completed Javascript event?

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to find a way to change the color of text in a form as a result of passing a validation by another JavaScript function. Is there an easy way to do this?

Example of the element I want to update the color for:

```
<form name="contact" method="post" action="send_form_email.php" novalidate>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
          <label for="nameInput">Name:*</label>
          <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" id="nameInput" placeholder="E.g. Alan Turing" oninput="bootstrapValidate('#nameInput', 'required:Please fill out this field')">
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
            <label for="emailInput">Email:*</label>
            <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="emailInput" placeholder="E.g. name@domain.com" oninput="bootstrapValidate('#emailInput', 'email:Enter a valid E-Mail!|required:Please fill out this field')">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
            <label for="telInput">Telephone:</label>
           <input name="tel" type="tel" class="form-control" id="telInput" placeholder="E.g. (01452) 714 xxx">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="msgInput">Message:*</label>
          <textarea name="msg" class="form-control" id="msgInput" placeholder="E.g. Hello world!" oninput="bootstrapValidate('#msgInput', 'required:Please fill out this field')"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </form>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Check out the `:valid:` selector. https://css-tricks.com/form-validation-ux-html-css/ (sorry for examples being in SASS)

Comment: Also, could you edit the post to give us the code for the whole form, and also state when the validation is triggered?

Comment: @RickardElimää I edited to show full form, the validation is "oninput="

Answer (score -1):

You can add CSS class to your element:

```js
// styles.css
.warning {
  color: red;
}

// scripts.js
document.getElementById('msgInput').classList.add('warning');
```

Comment: There is no any changes triggered here.

Comment: sorry, have a type in js - it should be `classList` instead of `classNames`

Answer (score -1):

For example `document. GetElementById('msgInput').style.color='#ABC666';`

Another way is to toglle a class containing a rule like so:
JS: `document. GetElementById('msgInput').classList.add('valid');`

CSS: `.valid { color: #ABC666; }`

Aforementioned JS code has to be placed in the event listener.